# Dual boot shutdown problem 18.04.2

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, shutdown

I got a problem while I'm shutting down my computer.

I can do everything and click power off:

[image: Screenshot]

if I click power off, it just gets stuck and I can't do anything, the only way is to hold the power button for 5 seconds:

[image]

Comment: open a terminal type `jouralctl -f` press the powerbutton and paste the output

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue long back when I was working on dual-boot mode. However, my issue was resolved when I updated my Video card.

So, I would recommend you do the same. Just check your video card and update it (if there's an update available). Most probably, your problem would be resolved. Let us know via comments section.